# Installing printer for all user profiles on xp machine

Tags: windows-xp, printing

I am using gprint as a shell call to print pdf files. I have to install the network printer first, but the program runs under a different account. Is there anyway to install a network printer under Windows XP so that it is available to all accounts on the machine?

Comment: Are you member of Administrator Group ?

Comment: if you have administrative rights to install then all users would be able to use the print !!

Comment: Both accounts are members of the local computer admin group. Installing the printer while logged in as user A, User B can not print to it.

Comment: This is already answered here http://superuser.com/questions/101441/install-printer-across-profiles-on-windows-xp