# Install printer across profiles on Windows XP?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, printer, user-profiles

I am using gprint as a shell call to print pdf files. I have to install the network printer first, but the program runs under a different account. Is there anyway to install a network printer under Windows XP so that it is available to all accounts on the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\server\printer
```

/ga adds it for all users on the machine
/n specifies the name of the printer in \\server\printername format

Answer (score 0):

For the completness you can also use the [prnmngr.vbs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868%28WS.10%29.aspx) script.

It's located in %SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US for Windows 7
For XP it's located in windows\system32.

To add printer for all users you use this command:

```
cscript prnmngr.vbs -ac -p "\\server\printer"
```